# Mongoose bulkWrite $set a field only if it's not already set

Tags: mongoose

I have a model where one of the fields should only but set (upsert) when it's not already set. Is there an easy way to do that in one call, instead of reading all the docs, examining the fields, and setting the field in multiple calls?

e.g.

```
export interface IBaby {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  createdAt: Date,
  updatedAt: Date,
}

const BabySchema = new Schema<IBaby>({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

const Baby = mongoose.model<IBaby>('Baby', BabySchema));

Baby.bulkWrite([{
  updateOne: {
    filter: { ... },
    update: {$set: {name: 'Prince'}}, // set only when name is not already set
    upsert: true,
  }
}]);
```

In the above example, I only want to set the name of the baby if it's not already set in the bulkWrite operation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a filter that any record doesn't have value or exits.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).